# IIS Express Returning HTTP 400 for WCF RESTful Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis-express

I have a WCF RESTful Web Service (using webHttpBinding) that is returning a 400 when I try to call a web service method on it.

If I go to mywebservice.svc, I get the standard WCF web service page.         But if I go to /mywebservice.svc/some/rest/service/url, I get an Http 400.  Every single time.  Doesn't matter the parameters, or the method being called.

Here's what we've looked at so far:

1. Looked at IIS Express logs.  There is no Win32 status (i.e. status 0) to go along with the HTTP Status
2. Turned on WCF logging.  Nothing is logged by WCF, which suggests the request isn't even making it that far.
3. Tried debugging our method, but the breakpoint never gets hit.
4. Tried running the service under Cassini.  Same result (http 400).
5. Tried another user on the problematic machine.  Same result.

We know that this works on other machines.  The problematic machine is using VS 2010 on Win XP.  We are using WCF 4.0

I know there isn't much to go on here because we don't have a specific error message, but given where we've looked, does anybody have any suggestions on where to look next?

**UPDATE:  Added Code Samples**
Here is the definition of my with one method, and the implementation of that method.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMAMDataWebService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Contracts/{taxID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    ContractCollection Contracts(string taxID);
}

public ContractCollection Contracts(string taxID)
{
    ContractCollection contracts = new ContractCollection();

    try
    {
        contracts = _contractService.GetContracts(taxID);
    }
    catch (RstsException rEx)
    {
        if (!rEx.Logged)
            _errorLogger.LogError(rEx);

            WebFault.ThrowFault(rEx, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RstsException rEx = new RstsException(ex);
            _errorLogger.LogError(rEx);

            WebFault.ThrowFault(rEx, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }

        if (contracts.Count == 0)
        {
            WebFault.ThrowFault(Strings.ObjectNotFound, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return contracts;
    }
```

I'm calling it with a web browser, i.e.  MAMDataWebService.svc/Contracts/123456789

I'm convinced this has to be a permissions problem, but I"m not sure what.  It works on all our Win 7 machines using VS 2010, but a few users still have XP and they're the ones with the problem.  But without any errors, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: How are you calling you service? through javascript? Can you show your code so we can get an idea of what could be the problem.

Comment: Does the problematic machine have MVC installed? It might not understand routing...

Comment: @Aron, this is using WCF to implement the REST service, so I don't think MVC matters, does it?  I will post some code samples.

Comment: Turns out this was a problem with our unity configuration.  It wasn't logging an error anywhere that we could find though, which made it difficult to find.